# Pandas Python (CSV) - Accessing data from tables and using that data -

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have three csv files - Supply, Demand and Hotelling.

I want to go to supply table, sum values in a given column where team_belong = "someteamname", and then write this summed up value into Hotelling file against the same team.

I am completely new to python. I want to be able to go into supply and demand tables, perform some basic calculations based on conditions and write them into the Hotelling table basically.

This is what I have so far, and now I am struggling to continue further:
[Current Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXTvu.png)

Comment: Copy-paste the code instead of posting it as an image.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("supplytable.csv")

df[df[team_column]==team_name][column_name].sum()
```

I suggest you to go through some online course on tutorial on pandas because this is the basics of pandas.